# How can I keybind opening a new terminal to the right of my current opened files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim, vscode-keybinding

Currently I have the below snippet of code that doesn't really seem to do what I want it to do under my vim normal mode keybindings:

```
    {
        "before": ["<Leader>", "f", "t"],
        "commands": [
            "workbench.action.terminal.newInActiveWorkspace",
            "workbench.action.terminal.focus",
            "workbench.action.moveEditorToNextGroup"
        ],
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !terminalFocus && !quickInputVisible"
    },
```

I want it to open up a new terminal tab, and open it as a new tab of the files which are opened in the middle of VS Code (not on the bottom terminal part).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want one of these commands:

```
Terminal: Create New Terminal in Editor Area
workbench.action.createTerminalEditor  

Terminal: Create New Terminal in Editor Area to the Side  (i.e., as a split/new group)
workbench.action.createTerminalEditorSide
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a VS Code command to change the location of a panel or open a panel in a specific location.

I do know that you can change the default location of all the panels by doing something like `"workbench.panel.defaultLocation": "right"`. You might need to close and reopen VS Code after changing that setting for it to take effect.

In newer versions of VS Code, there's the secondary/auxillary sidebar, which you can drag panels and views into, so there's that.